# using registered variables from .podman_container_info module

Tags: ansible, podman

I'm attempting to use a registered variable from the output from the [containers.podman.podman_container_info](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/containers/podman/podman_container_info_module.html) ansible module. Basically I'm doing this the following

```
- name: checking if gitlab-runner is present
  containers.podman.podman_container_info:
    name: gitlab-runner
  register: gitlabrunner_status
```

However, the next step I want to add a conditional to only run the next step if this container is defined based on the name. For testing I'm just using the debug module, so here is what I have tried.

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: gitlabrunner_status.containers.Name
```

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: gitlabrunner_status["containers"]["Name"]
```

each attempt I ended up getting `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!` So how can I just pull the name from the output to use in a conditional, from this complex output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: gitlabrunner_status.containers.Name
```

Is giving you a `VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED` error, then make sure the parent variable has the content you expect. That is, start with a task like this:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: gitlabrunner_status.containers
```

Looking at that output, we see that `containers` is a list that looks like:

```
"gitlabrunner_status.containers": [
    {
        ...
        "Name": "gitlab-runner",
        ...
    }
]
```

Because `containers` is a **list**, we can't simply ask for  `gitlabrunner_status["containers"]["Name"]`. We need a list index into
the `containers` list:

```
- name: debug
  debug:
    var: gitlabrunner_status.containers.0.Name
```